# Timeout on 3 attempt

Tags: grapevine

I've set up two services with grapevine, a client server schema, I'm like the following problem, after the second request the server or the client returns me a timeout limit.

After calling the method RestResponse response = this.client.Execute (request) the RestResponse; To execute the request, so I saw it does not arrive on the server.
This always happens on 3 did I send the call

Comment: Post some code, or a link to some code, and we can help you out.

Comment: https://github.com/elvispdosreis/pki_server
https://github.com/elvispdosreis/pki_client

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y(v=vs.110).aspx
Apparently it is this configuration but it was not for the grapevine to release the connections

Comment: I found this article useful https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adarshk/2005/01/02/understanding-system-net-connection-management-and-servicepointmanager/

Comment: This appears to be related to the connection management configuration on System.Net for the client, limiting requests to the same resource to 2 by default. While I'm still looking for a good answer for how to resolve this, the article I previously linked to may provide a good starting point.